# My boss wants me to attend a meeting every day before work hours

Tags: software-industry, united-states, meetings, work-time, time-management

My manager at a software company I've worked at for a few years has asked me to join a status update (a standup if you are familiar with agile) meeting daily, before my normal work hours.  My boss didn't call this meeting, but a project manager did as he is primarily interested in the status of the issues.  This has proven difficult as I'm usually quite busy in the mornings, handling getting myself and my children ready for their day during this time, and for the most part unavailable.  I could rearrange my schedule to make it work, I just really don't want to do that.

To make matters worse, this meeting is pointless for me to attend, it is a status update on a project I have very little to do with.  Once every few weeks I may actually need to be there to say a few "status update" words.  These could easily be summarized during work hours, as they are not time critical.

I tried just not attending, but got caught and he asked me again to join.  I've explained my time commitments, and my lack of work on this project, but still he pressures me me to attend and "zone out" waiting to see if my name is called.

How can I better communicate that I do not wish to waste my time attending this meeting every day?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84978/discussion-on-question-by-jay-my-boss-wants-me-to-attend-a-meeting-every-day-bef).

Comment: Are you asking for a script for getting out of the meetings or do you just need the requests to attend to stop? It's not clear whether or not you are currently attending the meetings and that affects the answer.

Comment: Is there any conceivable reason that the meetings couldn't be inside your normal working hours, and if so would you be opposed to going to them? What time of day are your hours vs this meetings hours? Are there any people in the meeting remotely such as from other countries? I think some context might be helpful given that it's odd that you got in this situation to begin with.

Comment: Are they paying you overtime to go to these meetings?

Comment: "Outside my normal work hours" - Are *your* normal work hours different from the *company* normal work hours?

Comment: You are asking the wrong question. It should be "Hey, boss, does time in this meeting count as work hours? I'd think it should..." (I've worked on a project with people on schedules fully 12 hours apart. The only practical times for meetings were 8PM-10PM and 8AM-10AM. Management recognized that this was inconvenient and let us take some flex time out of the normal work day if we were on the evening end of that.)

Answer (score 234):

Isn't the real problem here that they are asking to have work meetings, outside of work hours? We have daily scrums slightly after the day starts so that people can get drinks/etc. and then do the meeting and focus on their day. I would argue that, given the meetings are for work, they should arrange them at the start of the work day and not before.

Also because they are daily, if for whatever reason they can't do it during your work hours (because its normal work hours for everyone else perhaps?) you could try working out the night before what you want to say and send it to someone that is in the meeting so it can be read out daily as a compromise.

The only reason for mandatory attendance is either so you have visibility on everything that is occurring or for them to discuss issues with you and the former you seem to not require and the latter shouldn't be done in a scrum anyway.

Comment: I agree with this - discussing the usefulness of a meeting is a thing, asking to attend outside work hours is another.

Comment: Good answer. Work hours or no meeting that's all

Comment: It's possible that this is a global company. One meeting attendee's start time may be another attendee's finish time. The company I work for has flexible hours for this reason - if I need to attend a 10PM meeting on Tuesday, there's no need for me to start work at 9AM.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly That doesn't really change that this meeting seems to occur _before_ OP's start time.

Comment: @Jmac, for my company that is an impossible requirement to be during "work hours" for every location.  (Tokyo, London, NYC, San Francisco)

Comment: @cdkMoose His comment was related to having the meeting during one location's start time and another location's end time.  If it's impossible to schedule a meeting during everyone's work hours, there should be provisions made, it's usually not an ideal solution to tell someone "our company works at different times so you have to work extra uncompensated time".

Comment: @Jmac, OP did not state this time was uncompensated, just outside normal hours.  My point was that you can't always make it work in normal business hours for all attendees

Comment: @JamesDonnelly If you "need to attend" meetings at 10PM five days a week, for the indefinite future, then what? Would you just start working evenings or nights instead of days, with no extra salary to compensate?

Comment: Yo, this is a software company!  Normal work hours are therefore a very elastic concept here.  It's perfectly possible that Jay's regular working hours are not some other manager's concept of 'normal', and that doesn't make either the work or the meeting invalid.

Comment: I've seen the standups moved to accomodate one colleague's schedule.

Comment: @GeorgeM I don't see how "flexible hours" would be relevant. If you still get paid, check. If not, those are not work hours, period. It doesn't make the meeting invalid, but it gives valid reason for Jay to opt out, since he wouldn't be compensated.

Comment: @Liquid Jay is not asking about compensation, and it doesn't sound like it's an issue.  He has an agreement with his manager about working hours, and the manager wants to break it arbitrarily.  Treating this problem like he's working for a government, and/or public access, and working hours are rigidly 9-5 is not helpful to the discussion, it's not the question.

Comment: @GeorgeM I am very well aware of the difference between flexible hours and "regular" working hours. Wathever Jay's agreement with his manager is, I'm assuming he gets properly compensated. Being asked to **work outside** that agreement is exactly the issue. I've got the impression that either we're misunderstanding each other or we fundamentally disagree on something major.

Comment: @Fattie I work at a software startup and what you said is 100% wrong. I get paid by the hour. Our schedule is flexible but we have office hours (and support hours!) that we are expected to work, and outside of which we are *not* expected to work. You are confusing “software” and “startup” with “toxic culture”. (Further, since I’m not in the US I wouldn’t call my job “insanely overpaid”. My compensation is good but it’s not out of the ordinary, given my level of qualification.)

Comment: It's possible that the meeting is within work hours, just not the work hours the op usually works.. see:  `before my normal work hours`

Comment: In the US, salaried workers are generally expected to work when they're asked to work.  It depends on the state (some limit unpaid "overtime" for salaried workers, etc.) and any specific contractual terms, of course.  But, unfortunately, what is "normal working hours" for even years at a time can change abruptly without reason and often without recourse, unless you can prove it's an attempt at constructive dismissal.

Comment: I'd like to add that if it's acceptable to do status reports by email, you need to send an email every day, not just when you have something to say.  Just so they don't think you're forgetting about them, so they know the status today is 'nothing to report'.

Comment: I think we all need to recognize that until the asker says the time that this meeting is relative to their start we can't comment much on it. This could very easily be just poor scheduling especially if everyone at his workplace is on pretty much the same schedule with maybe a difference in 1-2 hours between people. Everything here is making some pretty bold assumptions about why the meeting is at this poor time of day.

Comment: I can't understand how this is "outside of work hours" if the other people in the meeting are present.  They obviously have a range of work hours that the other attendees adhere to, but not the original poster.  For example, my company has "flex" hours.  7 to 3, 8 to 4, 9 to 5, 10 to 6, or 11 to 7.  You pick, but you must adjust and adapt to your team.  Critical meetings are between 11 and 3, but many meetings that are important, just not all-hands, are held outside that window.

Answer (score 67):

A few suggestions:

- Ask the meeting organizer if you can attend the meeting remotely, over email or chat for example. Send your update the prior evening or at some other convenient time.
- Ask the meeting organizer to move the meeting time to accommodate your schedule. If they won't, you can at least inform your supervisor that they didn't which is one way of demonstrating that you might not be needed anyways.
  *I know that this goes against some people's ideas about Agile, but if your Agile process isn't agile, I'm not sure it's really Agile.*

Comment: From the Agile Manifesto:  "People over process".

Comment: This is the best option I think.  Lots of people seem to want you to give your update verbally at the actual time of the meeting so I would suggest just connecting via your phone and use a wireless headset (which I'd try to get my boss to pay for if I didn't already have one).  Since it appears the asker doesn't really need to contribute anything or get any benefit from this meeting the fact that they are not really paying attention won't matter.  If this option is refused I'd try the "that's not very agile is it?" line on them.

Comment: Attending remotely is not the point. OP has stuff to do then, but IMO "move the meeting time" is dead-on!

Comment: "Ask the meeting organizer if you can attend the meeting remotely" No. It's outside of work hours

Comment: It sounds like the OP is already attending remotely.  He has to get his kids ready for school etc. in the mornings which he wouldn't be able to do if he was already at the office for this meeting.

Answer (score 28):

> ...my lack of work on this project, but still he pressures me me to attend and "zone out" waiting to see if my name is called.

The meeting an agile team standup.

One of the key tenets of agile is to maximise productivity by minimising time-wasting meetings. A standup should be short, informal, effective and useful to all attendees.

If it is not, then it is a waste of time.

Another key tenet of agile is that the rituals of any given process that you are following, such as Scrum, should not be considered to be carved in stone. The process should adapt to you rather than you adapting to the process.

It sounds to me as if your team is trying to be agile, but actually being far too rigid about it, and thereby missing the point.

I don't have any specific advice for you on how to approach your manager with this, but clearly there is a problem and you do need to discuss it. I hope the above will give you some useful ammunition to help you make your case.

Comment: Teaching a team how to follow agile when you're the new person who's there with minimal impact, in a standup which is not a retrospective, doesn't seem like a winning solution.

Comment: Scrum is one of the most rigid forms of agile, in my personal experience.

Comment: If someone who is only tangentially working on a project is a part of that project's _daily_ standup, _and_ they have time to zone out until their name is called, I'd say their standup is also too big.

Answer (score 23):

Ugh.. that's immensely irritating - you have my sympathies!

Since it sounds like your boss isn't going to just let this one go completely I'd suggest you offer him a compromise option where you can meet the business objectives but don't actually have to attend.

Try offering to write a status update message for the times when you *do* have something relevant to say and have that be delivered to whoever is chairing the meeting by close of business the previous day.

If this is *really* about getting your updates to the team then this should be sufficient from what you've described. If he pushes back on this with vague mumbling about "visibility" or similar then you can counter with the fact that the optics of you being there but "zoned out" (his words) are going to be worse than you not being there in the first place. If on the other hand he pushes back using the old "what if someone has a question?" line then offer that if they e-mail you the question you'll respond to any queries by time *x* (where time X is during your working day, reasonably early if possible).

Comment: Plus see if someone else from your team is regularly in at that early hour, and whether you can trade some other tedious late-afternoon obligation with them, so the team is represented but by a willing party.  Even if they know nothing about the project, it's OK as long as you send them an email update every afternoon.  The one you'd otherwise be sending that other manager if they were reasonable :-).

Comment: OP mentioned that it is not his boss that is asking him to attend, it's his project manager. Therefore his "real" boss may be able to do something about it.

Comment: This solves giving updates. It doesn't solve hearing everybody else's.

Comment: @CPHPython The meeting was called/created by a project manager but it is their boss pressing them to attend.

Answer (score 20):

First of all, I advise taking the "I don't need to be in this meeting" out of the equation. Debating whether that's true is not really the crux of your problem.

Personally I've always been of the opinion that status meetings are more useful than many people think, because they are by definition an opportunity for a group of people to raise issues that perhaps individually they had never considered. What if something comes up in the meeting that *does* somehow impact your own work, and nobody else can possibly know that, and you weren't there to hear it and interject? The purpose of the meeting is to cover these cases, not for a bunch of people to stand around rattling off what everybody else already knows.

But only you can know whether this is even remotely likely to be the case for you, *which means your project manager doesn't know either*, which means using this as an arguing point is never going to work. So just forget it.

The salient point is having meetings outside of work hours. *If* the meeting has been scheduled outside of everybody's core hours, you simply say "I cannot attend that — could you move it into working hours?" and that's that. You shall not be forced to work outside of work hours and this becomes a matter for complaint to HR if it continues.

On the other hand, if the meeting is in some people's work hours just not your typical personal hours, you have a problem. You can apply pressure, asking people to move the meeting. This used to work for me and daily stand-up would slide later and later into the morning. If unsuccessful, there's really not much you can do other than make a decision as to whether you prefer to start when you currently do, or prefer to remain on good terms with the authorities involved.

Good luck!

Comment: This answer is likely to be unpopular but I completely agree with you on every point.

Comment: Unless the project itself is on a completely different piece of software or product than what the OP is currently working on. In which case the work itself couldn't affect the OP's daily work.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck Agreed that if it's _entirely irrelevant_ and _has no plausible connection_ to the OP, then all bets are off really. But you'd better be sure about that! Arguably that's for the manager to decide as they see the bigger picture.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit based on the question it sounded like the OP is there in order to make his department or whatever look nice by making an appearance not to actually provide insight. The manager's statement even make it sound that way.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck Again you're not considering the insight that can be gained as well as that which could be provided.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit and that warrants them being required to come in for unpaid extra hours every day? If they aren't critical to the project they shouldn't be working extra hours unpaid because they may once in a while learn something or give an idea. Either they are working the project and extra hours are now a job requirement because it is crunch time and that is how things work in the industry or they aren't the working the project and there's no reason for them to be required to volunteer hours.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck It doesn't really warrant it no - I haven't really addressed the scenario you're discussing in my answer (perhaps I should) so my comments shouldn't be taken as disagreement, only a continuation of the discussion you started, and you make some fine points. We do still need to clarify whether these are "extra unpaid hours" (which I already stated is a firm _no_) or simply a move to align the OP with [possibly core] hours that everybody else is already doing, which gets more complicated.

Comment: Slight nuance: If the meeting is during hours that you should be available for work, you have a problem. If the meeting is in some people's work hours but not during hours when you should work, the project manager has a problem. -- Therefore I fully agree with this answer, and think that if there is any way to defend that you should not be expected to work during those hours, this is the strongest point for you to argue on.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin Yep this

Answer (score 17):

If the meeting is truly pointless for you, and you cannot contribute (as opposed to being unlikely to contribute), he's probably trying to expand his footprint in the organization, and using you as manpower to do it.

I'd suggest talking to him about his goals of having you attend the meeting, and if he shares them with you, you can gain a lot of favor by attempting to help him achieve them.

That said, you need to also suggest that you further his goals in a way you can sustain.  For example, you might suggest that by being late or nearly late to each meeting, you're probably projecting the wrong impression, so instead you'll try to go out to lunch with a few key players, or follow up in ways that can work with your schedule.

Comment: Note that if he doesn't share his goals, it will be hard for you to further them.  While I wouldn't express that to him, it should tell you a lot about your future performance.  You'll be judged against goals that you don't understand.  Odds are not good you'll achieve them, and odds are even better that he'll manage by noticing the details of following his instructions (as opposed to the actual achievement of his desires)

Answer (score 11):

As Agile, everyone's time is supposed to be taken into account. In my team, everyone is usually in the office by 9.30 AM, but there is one person who comes in later due to their daily routine. We scheduled the meeting at a time everyday after their arrival so that everyone is included. I think your manager can do the same and the fact that they are not is just wrong. You should address this with a person above you and the manager.

Answer (score 4):

This answer has been heavily rewritten and rearranged to make it (hopefully) easier to read. The idea and rationale hasn't changed however I have changed (weakened) one of my assumptions as it seems it was to far fetched (I read it between the lines taking also some questions from comments as an actual state).

1. Strategy

---

Further parts will provide explanation why I suggest this strategy, this is just a step by step idea how to solve the problem.

- First establish why your Line Manager (LM) wants you to be in those meetings and discuss with Project Manager (PM) what is his perspective (does he/she think it's needed?). It might be that it's about LM wanting to be up to date with the project status through you. Other option is that he thinks your participation in the project is crucial.
- Arrange a meeting with both LM and PM and
- If LM thinks your attendance is essential but PM not, try discussing the best way to keep track of the project status without your attendance to stand ups (if that's why LM wants you in the stand-ups) or how would it be best to have you in the meeting when you're really needed.
- Either way bring up that most of the time you're not participating in the project and your everyday presence brings little to no value while costs plenty of your time and *some of team time* so it would be best if you joined the meetings only when there is a direct reason for it - either you do something for the project at that specific time or project team needs some information from you (which in most cases can be achieved in some other way).
- If that fails but the time of the meetings is really outside of reasonable working hours, ask for rescheduling the meetings to some more convenient time.
- If both PM and LM agree you're needed in the meetings and it cannot be rescheduled that's probably all you can do. Always remember there is an atomic option if you really can't stand those meetings.

Be aware any other software development team you might join after leaving this one is likely to have stand ups as well. They might only be in more convenient hours. On the other hand the project also doesn't last forever. If this is the only problem and the above suggestions don't help, I recommend you just try to hang in there until the project ends.

2. Working hours and meeting schedule

---

Are your working hours actually defined? If you work in environment anything like mine (rather standard for software development company/department) there is a large flexibility in your working hours. Yet usually there are rules when you have to be available for meetings (e.g. 9 a.m. - 3 p.m. or even 9 a.m. - 5 p.m.). If you have any meeting planned within that range of time you just have to accept that.

If the meeting is outside of that time you can request moving it to other timeframe. Yet since you're apparently not a key participant, there is a huge risk that this request will be rejected. Usually you can't do much about it anyway but that might become a point in discussion why you should attend in the meetings only when really needed.

If you don't have any strict availability hours but the meeting is in reasonable time (8 a.m. still has to be considered reasonable!) then again, there is little you can do about it. Effectively your flexibility is then limited but it does not excess in any way what an employer might require from you. If the hour is unreasonable due to e.g. time zones difference (for example the meeting is at 6 a.m. or 6 p.m.) this can again work as an excuse to attend only when your participation is really valuable.

**Real life example:**
I work in a project where every Monday and Friday we have a meeting at 4 p.m. Having flexible working hours I like being early at work and leaving early, meaning I usually leave at 4 p.m. But on Mondays and Fridays I simply show up and leave an hour later. There is nothing I can do about that. Moreover the Monday meetings are often cancelled at the very last moment or even the host simply doesn't show. It changes nothing since when they happen I'm crucial to it.

3. Private stuff

---

Let's be plain about that. If you're within working hours your private stuff doesn't matter. Especially when we're talking about something planned upfront. Just accept it. Don't bring that on a table during a discussion or everything you'll get is a negative outcome. Look for other arguments that might support your case in discussion.

4. Value of the meetings

---

This is another topic that you need to weight very carefully and pick the right wording to avoid negative response.

Stand ups are often perceived as a waste of time by teams. There are several reasons for that, one of them is that people don't understand the purpose of that meeting. Second - they are led incorrectly and result in actual waste of time. If a stand up is run properly it should be a short meeting very efficient in exchanging information and putting everyone on the same page in terms who does what. It should also help to immediately address issues that happen during the project.

Yet what is important (I would even say critical in your case) - these are *internal project team* meetings. Apparently you're not part of the project team, just occasionally provide some service to them.

Stand ups should not serve as a means of providing the "external world" the status of the meeting. It actually makes those meeting less productive.

If the main reason why your manager wants you to attend those meetings is to keep track of the project status then you have a very strong case to discuss your attendance to those stand ups.

Since you're not a part of project team then according to Agile you should **not** attend those meetings unless there is a reason for that (e.g. you do something for the project *at that time*). It might be that your Line Manager (LM) wants to keep track of the project progress and uses your small involvement in the project as an opportunity to be "the inside guy". If that's the case, the best you can do is discussing with both LM and PM how to establish a good communication path so that your LM can be sure about the project status. If the project team uses some tools supporting project tracking (like JIRA, Rally or even Mantis or other Bug tracker), an access to such tool and some dashboards about the project status might do the trick without your involvement. Otherwise you might agree on some regular status meetings. Maybe there are some happening already, after all there should be some project status update for the sponsors. Other option might be some regular reports provided to LM.

If you are supposed to join the meetings because you're part of the project team, you should challenge it. If you provide only occasional service to the project there should be some agreed way to communicate when your involvement is needed. You should then attend stand ups while you're directly performing tasks for the project but only then.

You should first discuss that with the Project Manager (PM). He might be your ally here since your attendance to the meetings can render counterproductive.

5. Waste of time?

---

Anyway, avoid using the wording "waste of time" in the discussion with LM. Look at my answer so far - I use it really hardly. For a reason. Yet, if you insist on using this particular word, what you can do is bringing up another Big Word - **LEAN**. If there has been any attempts to introduce LEAN in your company you can bring it up claiming, that your attendance in the meeting is a waste *according to LEAN*. You should join only if it is a benefit for the project.

Comment: I struggled to read through everything, barely made it. I think you are covering much more than required, therefore I downvoted.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @problemofficer  , I'll try to reorganise it and make a bit more readable,

Comment: "Your private stuff doesn't matter" - every job has a cost for me, mostly my work, other stuff like commute, and I get an income. If the company wants to make changes like this, they change the equation. A job that was perfect because mum can take the kids to school before starting is suddenly much less perfect, so you tell the company that your cost went up. And other companies are suddenly much more attractive.

Comment: @gnasher729 that's why I specifically wrote about situation *within normal working hours*. After re-reading I see that it is outside of regular working hours (though the question is - are these aligned with the company standards, some people have the hours unofficially changed). While it certainly matters for the employee, employer might be less willing to listen to that. Yet you have a point, it isn't as straightforward and if the arrangement has been lasting, the managers should take it into account. I still would use it as one of the last arguments, just to support and strengthen others.

Answer (score 1):

**Establish why your manager wants you at this meeting, in clear terms.**

Your attendance at this meeting, like your job in general, isn't about you. It's about the needs of the organization as a whole.

As an illustrative example, we have a similar situation where I work. Every day, someone from our support org attends our stand-up. Maybe once a sprint, we have something important to tell this person. Maybe once every few months, that person has something to tell us. This exchange of information does relatively little for our support organization most of the time.

It's incredibly vital to our development effort, because it's one of the only times we get clear, unmitigated feedback from the field. It also provides both us and them with a shared context for future communication that provides value to both our teams in context for outside of the meeting.

It's a waste of *their* time, but it's an incredibly valuable contribution for *our* project.

This value isn't obvious from cursory or outside examination, and it really can't be perceived only by considering the situation from the individual perspective of the attendees or the events of the meetings. It's the downstream effects that are significant.

It's the bigger picture that matters.

**What asking management about this will get you:**

**It may educate you.**

You may discover, by talking this out with your management and/or with the project manager in question, that there are reasons for your attendance you may not have considered. This could lead to you providing, or gaining, more value in future meetings, and feeling less 'put out' by your compulsory attendance.

**It will empower you.**

Trying to 'get out of' a meeting is an inherently imbalanced negotiation between you and whomever is calling the shots.

Convincing them that your perspective and your values should be sufficient cause for them to change their mind is an uphill battle. Convincing them that their objectives aren't being fulfilled by this course of action is a much more evenly balanced dialogue.

---

Ultimately, the professional value you derive from and perceive in this meeting is only a small part of the bigger picture. If you can't frame your argument in terms of that bigger picture, it's not really reasonable to expect to convince anyone that the best course of action for the organization is to proceed as you would desire.

Comment: But forcing a person to join daily stand-up when the information exchange happens in 1 meeting out of 20 is an incredible waste of time of that person. Establish a better communication path outside of stand up instead.

Comment: @Ister Wasting one person's time may be a legitimate investment on behalf of the company. One person spending 30 minutes that get wasted most of the time may be worth 20 people not spending an extra 10 minutes on something because they're in the dark, for example. There is more to consider here than just one person's time, and the OP did not indicate that due diligence had been performed on attempting to understand any of the other factors.

Comment: @IronGremlin if you mean to say that they should be there in case something comes up that could maaaybe make sense. In reality though if it's something to be raised at the meeting known in advance then the person should be requested to come to that one meeting, not told to stay there everyday and certainly not during unpaid outside-of-work hours.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck - There are many valid reasons for face to face communication. Ultimately the core point I'm making here is that whether or not this 'wastes your time' isn't your call, it's your management's call. So figure out why management wants you there first before you start arguing about whether or not you should attend. The conversation needs to be about whether or not it suits the organization, not whether or not it suits the individual. What to do about getting paid is another conversation, but I do agree it's one that needs to happen.

Comment: @IronGremlin "isn't your call". It is my call as to whether it is my opinion that the meeting is a waste to have them there. I'm saying that if the person needs to give a monthly statement then they come in monthly. If it's a weekly statement then weekly. My point is that if the person is 100% never speaking at these meeting except those times then they should only be coming to the meeting those days, especially if the purpose is for them to give information and not for them to receive information. Just because it is managements decision doesn't mean an objective answer does not exist.

Comment: It just means that arguing with management is fruitless, and likely to end badly.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck - If your only evidence that this is objectively fruitless is your own failure to provide or gain anything that you personally feel is useful, that's not exactly ironclad reasoning. If you want to be objective, you need to figure out what the expectation of value actually is first before you decide you can't possibly provide or acquire it.

Comment: @IronGremlin im saying that protesting the meeting as being useful or not useful is fruitless which is what you yourself said before, because the management ultimately makes that decision. Whether or not the meeting actually *is* useful is tangential to whether the management *believes* it is useful.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck Why management _believes_ it is useful is, however, central to any dialogue you're going to have with them on the topic. Visa vi, don't try to weasel out of a meeting without first talking to management about why the **** you're supposed to be there. Whether or not you think it's valuable to you professionally isn't irrelevant, but it is only one part of a larger picture. You shouldn't have that argument with your management unless you can frame the conversation in terms of that larger picture.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck - Thanks for the discussion, it's given me some valuable ideas on how to re-phrase the answer to more accurately illustrate my point.

Comment: Once again that is literally what I am saying. You're agreeing with me. I'm saying that one shouldn't argue with management as it will not be fruitful. Management believes it is useful so even if it isn't useful no amount of action or discussion will convince them.

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

In 2023, with many people working from home:

If you usually commute from 8am to 9am and start work in the office at 9am, and the company wants you to join a meeting from 8am to 9am, then you could suggest that you join the meeting from home, then commute from 9am to 10am and arrive at the premises at 10am.

And obviously you can't have a company meeting before your work starts. Because your work starts with the meeting. So your work hours would be 8am to 9am, then 10am to whatever time.

(I did something similar when we worked with a company in Australia, 12 hours away, worst case: On some days, I would leave two hours early, then join a meeting from home with the Australian client from 8pm to 10pm. Of course it depends on your nature if that time is acceptable, I didn't mind).

All that said: If you are at work, you do what they ask you to do, and if they ask you to do something pointless then you do it. That's not the problem.

The problem is that your cost of going to work is going up dramatically because you have to find someone to take your kids to school etc. There is a balance between your income, and your cost (working, commute, etc. ) and their request changes that balance. They are making your job much less attractive for you, and by the same sign, jobs at other companies are suddenly a lot more attractive.

Many people have the attitude that that is not your companies problem, but it is. And of course your managers may not realise the problem (they wouldn't unless you tell them), and once they are aware, they might be willing to rearrange things. Of course some managers don't give a **** about you, but some do. There might not even be any particular reason for the time, except that a decision needed to be made, and any other time might be just as good for everyone involved.

(Another place I worked from 10am to 7pm, because there was little traffic at these times. Working 9am to 6pm, I would have had to leave two hours earlier and would be back home at the same time, because of traffic. If they had asked me to work an hour earlier, no way. )

Answer (score 0):

Standup meetings related to a project usually don’t last forever. Most of the time they are created when a project is having difficulties and the standup is implemented in order to give attention to daily issues to get the project back on track. Once the issues are resolved, the stand up usually goes away.

Also, you have voiced your opinion to your boss but he wants you there anyway. If you are a salaried employee, there is really nothing you can do at this point but to attend. If you have a decent relationship with your boss, sounds like he wants you to hear the issues to give you insights into project dynamics. The only thing you can do is to attend and after a short time, revisit your attendance with him if you still feel your are not deriving any benefit from attending.

Comment: Yes, but the issue at hand here is that the OP is not being paid to come to these meetings. They are expected to come to these meetings while still working their regular hours without extra pay or time off. It sounds like the OP would be fine with the meetings if it were within regular hours or paid.

Comment: Understand but if he/she is salaried, nothing they can do but to attend. As a salaried professional, this is part of the job.

Comment: Based  on their statements it seems clear that they are hourly. Some places consider it normal practice for hourly employees in software to work extra hours unpaid when a project is behind schedule or close to completion. The issue is that the OP isn't working on the project and so they shouldn't be forced to volunteer their time.

Comment: Granted that might not be the situation the asker in but it seems like that's what they are describing.

Comment: fyi, "descent", should most probably be "decent". (minor edits are frowned upon on Stack Exchange because they bump the question to the start page, also it is not possible to edit with only one char change, that is why I am not editing it in).

Comment: @kedavle I always thought that was a daft rule. There should be "edit" vs. "fix typo".

Answer (score -2):

### Check your contract, salaried or hourly

First, determine are you [salaried or hourly](https://www.thebalancesmb.com/salary-vs-hourly-employee-397909) employee.

If hourly, your strategy would be based on demand to be compensated for overtime. Simply state to your manager that you are not **legally** obliged to put extra hours without pay. Emphasize on "legally" , this implies that you already have legal council on this matter. Hopefully, your manager doesn't have authority to pay you extra, so some kind of solution would happen where you don't need to attend meetings, which is exactly what you want.

If salaried, things could get complicated. Best policy in this case is to state to your manager that you simply cannot attend the meetings. Theoretically, as salaried employee you still have some rights for overtime compensation, but this rarely happens, so don't count on it.

In any case, be prepared for **deal breaker** . If you really cannot attend those meetings, or your manager really needs you there, it would be prudent to simply brush up your resume. This is especially true in US, with employment at will.

Comment: Yes, I agree: this is a legal issue. What if other "project manager" decides to have another meeting at the end of the day (after working hours)? Since it is only a manager (and not his boss), I'd add that talking to his boss may help further resolving compensation issues before considering moving out.

Comment: Another reason for revising the CV is a manager, who doesn't care for his employees.

Comment: Why go into legalities if you are hourly? It goes without saying that you bill for the hours because you are working. If it is customary to discuss overtime then have that discussion. I don't think compensation is the problem here though.

Comment: @stoj My impression is that manager pushes OP to join meetings from home, i.e. in his free time, therefore avoiding to pay overtime. OP didn't clarify is he hourly or salaried employee, this could make huge difference. My impression is that OP's manager want to squeeze more time from OP without compensating. OP doesn't want more money, but asking for more money could bring him more time.

Comment: @CPHPython not to mention that the OP says outside of normal hours implying that they are suddenly being expected to stay for their normal hours in addition to the meetings.

Comment: @rs.29 indeed it sounds like in the question that the OP is expected to work them and normal hours without compensation.

Comment: The hourly thing could fall apart if it's really important to this manager and he says "fine, you can leave 10 minutes early to make up for it."  OP should be prepared to have this argument pulled out from under him if he makes it.

Comment: @nasch I don't think it is a 10 minute matter, from OP's question it looks like it is one of those long, boring and pointless meetings that only serve to stroke some top manager's ego.

Comment: Very few things in life are a legal issue. Most things can be sorted out some way between reasonable adults. Before legal issues come into play, you need to figure out what is the cost of the change for you, then your manager needs to be told what your cost is so they can compare it to their benefits, _then_ the manager needs to consider how attractive changing jobs becomes for you with this change, and only then does it get legal.